# What is the difference between xgb.train and xgb.XGBRegressor (or xgb.XGBClassifier)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, xgboost

I already know "`xgboost.XGBRegressor` is a Scikit-Learn Wrapper interface for XGBoost."

But do they have any other difference?

Comment: Differences in parameter names, differences in input, difference in evaluation strategies. Please look at the [python api](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) and [github page](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/python-package). This is not a good question. If you have any difficulties in understanding the output from the two approaches, please ask a detailed question with code.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[`xgboost.train`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.training) is the low-level API to train the model via gradient boosting method.

`xgboost.XGBRegressor` and `xgboost.XGBClassifier` are the wrappers (*Scikit-Learn-like wrappers*, as they call it) that prepare the `DMatrix` and pass in the corresponding objective function and parameters. In the end, the `fit` call simply boils down to:

```py
self._Booster = train(params, dmatrix,
                      self.n_estimators, evals=evals,
                      early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
                      evals_result=evals_result, obj=obj, feval=feval,
                      verbose_eval=verbose)
```

This means that **everything** that can be done with `XGBRegressor` and `XGBClassifier` is doable via underlying `xgboost.train` function. The other way around it's obviously not true, for instance, some useful parameters of `xgboost.train` are not supported in `XGBModel` API. The list of notable differences includes:

- `xgboost.train` allows to set the `callbacks` applied at end of each iteration.
- `xgboost.train` allows training continuation via `xgb_model` parameter.
- `xgboost.train` allows not only minization of the eval function, but maximization as well.

Answer (score 14):

@Maxim, as of xgboost 0.90 (or much before), these differences don't exist anymore in that [xgboost.XGBClassifier.fit](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier.fit):

- has `callbacks`
- allows contiunation with the `xgb_model` parameter
- and supports the same builtin eval metrics or custom eval functions

What I find is different is `evals_result`, in that it has to be retrieved separately after fit (`clf.evals_result()`) and the resulting `dict` is different because it can't take advantage of the name of the evals in the watchlist ( `watchlist = [(d_train, 'train'), (d_valid, 'valid')]` ) .

Answer (score 5):

From my opinion the main difference is the training/prediction speed.

For further reference I will call the `xgboost.train` - 'native_implementation' and `XGBClassifier.fit` - 'sklearn_wrapper'

I have made some benchmarks on a dataset shape (240000, 348)

Fit/train time:
`sklearn_wrapper` time = 89 seconds
`native_implementation` time = 7 seconds

Prediction time:
`sklearn_wrapper` = 6 seconds
`native_implementation` = 3.5 milliseconds

I believe this is reasoned by the fact that `sklearn_wrapper` is designed to use the pandas/numpy objects as input where the `native_implementation` needs the input data to be converted into a xgboost.DMatrix object.

In addition one can optimise n_estimators using a `native_implementation`.

Comment: "native implementation" needs DMatrix as input. Have you considered the time needed to convert your data into the DMatrix when calculating the time of "native implementation"?

Answer (score 1):

@Danil is suggesting significant differences in speed and @Mohammad correctly points out the necessity to convert data to DMatrix structure. So I have tried to replicate the benchmark in the [Kaggle notebook environment](https://www.kaggle.com/code/svendaj/xgboost-native-vs-xgbregressor-sklearn-wrapper).

The results showed no major training/predicting speed difference among `xgboost native` and `sklearn_wrapper`.

### EDIT: adding code of benchmark as suggested in comments

```py
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
xgb.__version__
```

'1.6.1'

```py
    # training data
    X = np.random.rand(240000, 348)
    y = np.random.rand(240000)
```

### Benchmark xgboost native implementation

````
```python
%%time
# convert training data
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X, label=y)
````

````
CPU times: user 3.61 s, sys: 505 ms, total: 4.12 s\
Wall time: 1.56 s

```python
    %%time
    # train the model with default parameters
    model = xgb.train({'objective':'reg:squarederror'},dtrain,10)
````

CPU times: user 6min 8s, sys: 700 ms, total: 6min 9s
Wall time: 1min 34s

```py
    %%time
    # predict with trained model
    prediction = model.predict(dtrain)
```

CPU times: user 818 ms, sys: 1.01 ms, total: 819 ms
Wall time: 209 ms

### Benchmark Scikit-Learn Wrapper interface for XGBoost

```py
    %%time
    model = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=10)
    model.fit(X,y)
```

CPU times: user 6min 15s, sys: 1.2 s, total: 6min 16s
Wall time: 1min 37s

XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', callbacks=None,
colsample_bylevel=1, colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1,
early_stopping_rounds=None, enable_categorical=False,
eval_metric=None, gamma=0, gpu_id=-1, grow_policy='depthwise', importance_type=None, interaction_constraints='',
learning_rate=0.300000012, max_bin=256, max_cat_to_onehot=4,
max_delta_step=0, max_depth=6, max_leaves=0, min_child_weight=1,
missing=nan, monotone_constraints='()', n_estimators=10, n_jobs=0,
num_parallel_tree=1, predictor='auto', random_state=0, reg_alpha=0,
reg_lambda=1, ...)

```py
    %%time
    prediction_1 = model.predict(X)
```

CPU times: user 1.48 s, sys: 1.99 ms, total: 1.48 s
Wall time: 380 ms

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32634252)